# Converting ppm to png

Tags: c++, image

In Linux I am getting .PPM files as the image format, this needs to be converted to PNG and then saved.  I was looking at some API's to achieve this conversion from PPM to PNG.  Can this be done using GDI+, as this would become native?

If that is not possible then I think freeimage or pnglib can accomplish that, however I would prefer to use native gdi+ if possible.

Answer (score 40):

Quick and dirty: download Imagemagick and use it from CLI:

```
convert xx.ppm xx.png
```

or use Imagemagick's dll API

Answer (score 17):

Whilst **ImageMagick** will happily do what you need, it is actually a sledgehammer to crack a nut, and considerably more cumbersome and space and time-consuming to install than the **NetPBM** suite.

With that, you would do:

```
pnmtopng image.ppm > result.png
```

Comment: I can't find how to download it. Can you provide a link please? Thanks! Also I use Visual Studio 2017, so is there a function I can call?

Comment: On my Mac installing imagemagick is as easy as `brew install imagemagick`.

Comment: ya, I can't find this with `brew help` or on `packages.ubuntu.com`

Comment: @DanielLizik It should be here... https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=Netpbm&searchon=names&suite=cosmic&section=all

Comment: On **macOS**, it is `brew install netpbm`

Comment: @MarkSetchell Can you tell _why_ you consider ImageMagick to be a sledgehammer in comparison to NetPBM? What is the difference?

Comment: @Thomas ImageMagick is a massively powerful and comprehensive suite of tools. A lot of that power comes from leveraging other packages, such as libtiff, libjpeg, XML tools, X11, fftw, OpenEXR, Cairo, Pango, freetype, Ghostscript, heif, rsvg, CMS. The large number of dependencies can lead to incompatibilities and difficulties installing and configuring. By comparison, NetPBM is self-contained. Don't get me wrong, I am in awe of ImageMagick's abilities, but sometimes you need a pair of scissors and sometimes you need a chainsaw, crane and industrial, hydraulic sheet-steel cutters.

Comment: Thank you!!  To me, it is astonishing that the package maintainer wouldn't symlink `pnmtopng` as `ppmtopng` given that it can apparently handle **both** PNM and PPM files.

Answer (score 5):

you can use ffmpeg, for batch conversion you can do

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in *.ppm;
  do name=`echo "$i" | cut -d'.' -f1`
  echo "$name"
  ffmpeg -i "$i" "${name}.png"
done
```

Comment: Rather than the roundabout name=$( ... cut ...) approach, use either name=$(basename ...) or name=${i%.ppm}

Answer (score 0):

Well GDI+ does not natively support the PPM format.  So you will need a [library](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/libnetpbm.html) whatever you do.

Answer (score -1):

You can use ImageMagick library :

http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php

but it does lots of other things.